# How to configure the project level build.gradle for all new projects?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

My organization uses its own jrog artifactory and it's an internal website with username and password. Every time I create a new project in Android Studio, I need to change the project-level build.gradle file with my custom code and add the credentials in gradle.properties. Is there a way, where I will get my custom code loaded in build.gradle file every time I create a new project?

I am using Android Studio 4.1

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Initialization Scripts](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html) (a.k.a. init scripts) to configure your corporate maven repository globally for all your projects:

`$user_home/.gradle/init.gradle` :

```
// configure private repo for all projects (root & sub projects)
allprojects {
    repositories {    
        mavenLocal()
        repositories {
            maven {
                name "Corporate repository"
                url "https://mycompany.org/maven-public"
                credentials {
                    username = ?????
                    password = ******
                }
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

Values for username & password can also be set globally , e.g in your user-level gradle properties `$user_home/.gradle/gradle.properties`

If you need to share this setup among your team, you could also create your own corporate Gradle wrapper distribution, which can pre-configure stuff like defaults plugins or common repositories; this requires more work, but you can find example here : https://blog.mrhaki.com/2012/10/gradle-goodness-distribute-custom.html